# MATLAB: Saving parameters inside ode45 using 'assignin'

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm running a set of ODEs with ode45 in MATLAB and I need to save one of the variables (that's not the derivative) for later use. I'm using the function 'assignin' to assign a temporary variable in the base workspace and updating it at each step. This seems to work, however, the size of the array does not match the size of the solution vector acquired from ode45. For example, I have the following nested function:

```
function [Z,Y] = droplet_momentum(theta,K,G,P,zspan,Y0)

options = odeset('RelTol',1e-7,'AbsTol',1e-7);
[Z,Y] = ode45(@momentum,zspan,Y0,options);

function DY = momentum(z,y)

    DY = zeros(4,1);

    %Entrained Total Velocity
    Ve = sin(theta)*(y(4));

    %Total Relative Velocity
    Urs = sqrt((y(1) - y(4))^2 + (y(2) - Ve*cos(theta))^2 + (y(3))^2);

    %Coefficients
    PSI = K*Urs/y(1);
    PHI = P*Urs/y(1);

    %Liquid Axial Velocity
    DY(1) = PSI*sign(y(1) - y(4))*(1 + (1/6)*(abs(y(1) - y(4))*G)^(2/3));

    %Liquid Radial Velocity
    DY(2) = PSI*sign(y(2) - Ve*cos(theta))*(1 + (1/6)*(abs(y(2) - ...
        Ve*cos(theta))*G)^(2/3));

    %Liquid Tangential Velocity
    DY(3) = PSI*sign(y(3))*(1 + (1/6)*(abs(y(3))*G)^(2/3));

    %Gaseous Axial Velocity
    DY(4) = (1/z/y(4))*((PHI/z)*sign(y(1) - y(4))*(1 + ...
        (1/6)*(abs(y(1) - y(4))*G)^(2/3)) + Ve*Ve - y(4)*y(4));

    assignin('base','Ve_step',Ve);
    evalin('base','Ve_out(end+1) = Ve_step');
end

end
```

In the above code, theta (radians), K (negative value), P, & G are constants and for the sake of this example can be taken as any value. Zspan is just the integration time step for the ODE solver and Y0 is the initial conditions vector (4x1). Again, for the sake of this example these can take any reasonable value. Now in the main file, the function is called with the following:

```
Ve_out = 0;
[Z,Y] = droplet_momentum(theta,K,G,P,zspan,Y0);
Ve_out = Ve_out(2:end);
```

This method works without complaint from MATLAB, but the problem is that the size of Ve_out is not the same as the size of Z or Y. The reason for this is because MATLAB calls the ODE function multiple times for its algorithm, so the solution is going to be slightly smaller than Ve_out. As am304 suggested, I could just simply calculated DY by giving the ode function a Z and Y vector such as DY = momentum(Z,Y), however, I need to get this working with 'assignin' (or similar method) because another version of this problem has an implicit dependence between DY and Ve and it would be too computationally expensive to calculate DY at every iteration (I will be running this problem for many iterations).

Comment: Again, you need to show self-contained code. What's in zspan?

Comment: The code is relatively long and it can't be shortened and still be self contained. Zspan is just the integration time (or space) step (similar to tspan). It just tells the ODE solver to solve from t0 to tf. I can include a self contained code if needed, but it's much longer.

Comment: An aside: Why not make your objective function a [nested function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html), and then use a variable that's visible to both the objective function and the caller? This avoids the use of `evalin` and family, which are especially error-prone.

Comment: This algorithm is part of a larger iterative cycle and I put them in separate function files simply to keep things neat. It becomes significantly cluttered otherwise. Using separate function files has ridiculously slowed down my iterative process, unfortunately.

Comment: @Kimusubi Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), learn about [self contained code](http://sscce.org/) and understand that sometimes we might be nicer if you ask [smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). And especially don't teach me how the ODE solver works. I know how it works... Heck I can see the problem from a mile away, but you're not helping me to help you.  This is the second time in a few days that you're not giving me debuggable code. Try again!

Comment: I'm sorry that you're offended, but you asked what 'zspan' is so I explained it. I'm not exactly sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Rasman I went ahead and included a self contained code, though I'm not sure if it's going to be much help.

Comment: it will be of help when I can run `[Z,Y] = droplet_momentum(theta,K,G,P,zspan,Y0);` without an error message. And self-contained code doesn't mean you need to show me your code, rather it means you can show a simplified code that reproduces the problem. Zspan can be expressed in several different ways and until you tell me what's in there, I can't start building a solution for you

Comment: One thing I forgot to add is that K is a negative value. I've already made the edit to the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so let's start off with a quick example of an SSCCE:

```
function [Z,Y] = khan

options = odeset('RelTol',1e-7,'AbsTol',1e-7);
[Z,Y] = ode45(@momentum,[0 12],[0 0],options);
end

function Dy = momentum(z,y)
Dy = [0 0]';

Dy(1) = 3*y(1) + 2* y(2) - 2;
Dy(2) = y(1) - y(2);

Ve = Dy(1)+ y(2);

    assignin('base','Ve_step',Ve);
    evalin('base','Ve_out(end+1) = Ve_step;');

    assignin('base','T_step',z);
    evalin('base','T_out(end+1) = T_step;');
end
```

By running `[Z,Y] = khan` as the command line, I get a complete functional code that demonstrates your problem, without all the headaches associated. My patience for this has been exhausted: live and learn.

> This seems to work, however, the size of the array does not match the
>   size of the solution vector acquired from ode45

Note that I added two lines to your code which extracts time variable. From the command prompt, one simply has to run the following to understand what's going on:

```
Ve_out = [];
T_out = [];
[Z,Y] = khan;
size (Z)
size (T_out)
size (Ve_out)
plot (diff(T_out))

ans =
   109     1

ans =   
     1   163

ans =
     1   163
```

[image]

Basically ode45 is an iterative algorithm, which means it will regularly course correct (that's why you regularly see diff(T) = 0). You can't force the algorithm to do what you want, you have to live with it.

So your options are
  1. [Use a fixed step algorithm](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1TJ3GZ/index.html?solution=1-1TJ3GZ)
  2. Have a function call that reproduces what you want after the ode45 algorithm has done its dirty work. (am304's solution)
  3. Collects the data with the time function, then have an algorithm parse through everything to removes the extra data.

Comment: You can also create a time series with your data and use resample to get `Ve` to the same size as `Z` and `Y`:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.resample.html

Comment: Another possibility is to reformulate your differential equations so that `Ve` is one of the outputs. You would need to add `dY(5) = % equation for dVe`. Then `Ve` would be returned as `Y(5)`.

Comment: @am304 Yes and no. You end up adding several layers of complexity to that. in my example. dVe = d(dy(1)) + dy(2). But d(dy(1)) is not defined, therefore you will need another differential parameter which will require rewriting your equations to take it(them) into account (or risk creating "coupled" equations)

Answer (score 1):

Can you not do something like that? Obviously check the sizes of the matrices/vectors are correct and amend the code accordingly.

```
[Z,Y] = droplet_momentum2(theta,K,G,P,zspan,Y0);
DY = momentum(Z,Y);
Ve = sin(theta)*(0.5*z*DY(4) + y(4));
```

i.e. once the ODE is solved, computed the derivative `DY` as a function of `Z` and `Y` (which have just been solved by the ODE) and finally `Ve`.

Comment: I actually did that, but I was just trying to figure out how to do with 'assignin' and 'evalin'. The reason I wanted to do that is because I need to implement for a slightly different version of the code where there is an implicit dependence on DY and VE and it would be very computationally heavy to solve for DY twice (once for the ODE and once again to get Ve). Since I'm running many iterations for various initial conditions, all these extra steps are going to add up.

Comment: If that's the case, then please reformulate your question. As is, it makes no sense to abuse `assignin` and `evalin` and you likely will not get it to work.

Comment: Another alternative to @am304's solution is to have `ode45` output only one variable. It will be a struct. You can then use this struct in conjunction with the [`deval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deval.html) function to evaluate the solution, or subsets of the solutions at arbitrary points in time using the appropriate [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).

Comment: I'm using assignin and evalin per a mathworks document suggesting solutions to this very problem, but I do agree with you, it's not a very good method.